# What is the best way to avoid deadlocks when using SELECT/LIMIT 1/FOR UPDATE?

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions, database-deadlocks

I have the following two transactions which are causing deadlocks:

**Transaction 1:**

```
SELECT *
FROM bots b
WHERE b.status = :available
AND (b.last_checked_at IS NULL OR b.last_checked_at < :fiveMinsAgo)
ORDER BY b.last_checked_at ASC
LIMIT 1
FOR UPDATE

*AND* (I don't think that this statement is part of the issue)

UPDATE bots b
SET b.last_checked_at = :now
WHERE b.id = :botId
```

**Transaction 2:**

```
SELECT b.*, bu.*
FROM bots b
LEFT JOIN bot_users bu ON bu.id = b.assigned_to_bot_user_id
WHERE b.currency = :currency
AND (b.status = :available OR (b.status = :reserved AND bu.last_action_at < :threeMinsAgo))
AND ((b.slot_count - b.items_count) >= :amount)
ORDER BY b.keys_count ASC, b.id ASC
LIMIT 1
FOR UPDATE

*OR*

SELECT b.*, bu.*
FROM bots b
LEFT JOIN bot_users bu ON bu.assigned_bot_id = b.id
WHERE b.currency = :currency
AND (b.status = :available OR (b.status = :reserved AND bu.last_action_at < :threeMinsAgo))
AND (b.keys_count >= :amount)
ORDER BY b.keys_count DESC, b.id ASC
LIMIT 1
FOR UPDATE

*AND*

UPDATE bots SET status = :reserved WHERE id = :id
```

**Explanation:**

Transaction #1 is selecting 1 bot that is available and that hasn't been checked within the last 5 minutes, checking it, and then updating the last_checked_at field.

Transaction #2 (case 1) is selecting 1 bot that handles a certain currency, has a status of available or reserved & "expired" (no user action for 3 mins), and has enough slots available.

Transaction #2 (case 2) is selecting 1 bot that handles a certain currency, has a status of available or reserved & "expired" (no user action for 3 mins), and has enough keys for the amount requested.

**Notes:**

There are indexes on b.keys_count, b.currency, and b.status.

**Example deadlock:**

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2014-07-04 20:33:11 7fc46f270700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 1657246652, ACTIVE 0 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 4 lock struct(s), heap size 1184, 36 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 30422870, OS thread handle 0x7fc46f437700, query id 1217244940 10.0.88.8 mydb Creating sort index
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 4752665 page no 3 n bits 176 index `PRIMARY` of table `mydb`.`bots` trx id 1657246652 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 1657246644, ACTIVE 0 sec updating or deleting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
10 lock struct(s), heap size 2936, 37 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 30422999, OS thread handle 0x7fc46f270700, query id 1217244943 10.0.88.8 mydb updating
UPDATE bots SET status = 1 WHERE id = 19
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 4752665 page no 3 n bits 176 index `PRIMARY` of table `mydb`.`bots` trx id 1657246644 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 4752665 page no 6 n bits 168 index `status_idx` of table `mydb`.`bots` trx id 1657246644 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

It looks like the queries are locking most of the rows, instead of just the one.

What is the best way to prevent these deadlocks? Is it best to not use FOR UPDATE in transaction #1, and then attempt to acquire a lock with an ID-based selection that also includes the other conditions? For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM bots b
WHERE b.status = :available
AND (b.last_checked_at IS NULL OR b.last_checked_at < :fiveMinsAgo)
ORDER BY b.last_checked_at ASC
LIMIT 1

SELECT *
FROM bots b
WHERE b.id = :idSelectedAbove
AND b.status = :available
AND (b.last_checked_at IS NULL OR b.last_checked_at < :fiveMinsAgo)
FOR UPDATE
```

This will obviously fail a certain percentage of the time, depending on various factors.

Is there any way to lock only the one row when using ORDER BY, FOR UPDATE?

Answer (score 0):

Consider simulating record locks with `GET_LOCK()` and scrapping the `FOR UPDATES`;

Choose a name specific to the rows you want locking. e.g. `'bot_id_1'`.

Call `SELECT GET_LOCK('bot_id_1',30)` to lock the name `'bot_id_1'`.. it will return 1 and set the lock if the name becomes available, or return 0 if the lock is not available after 30 seconds (the second parameter is the timeout).

Use `SELECT RELEASE_LOCK('bot_id_1')` when you are finished.

Be aware; You will have to use the same names in each transaction and calling `GET_LOCK()` again in a transaction will release the previously set lock.

[**`GET_LOCK()` docs**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html)

Comment: Thanks Arth. I ended up adding an extra status "quarantined", so users select bots that are available, and checks are run on bots that are quarantined. This avoids the issue entirely. :-)